# Sqlite3 Deleting a searched record from a tkinter box

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, sql-delete

I am currently coding a program which has an account system. When deleting an account a user searches for the records details, which if successful, appears in a box on the screen. My problem is that I cannot find a solution to deleting the searched record. This is my current code:

```
def delete_member(self):    
            conn = sqlite3.connect(r"F:\Program\Accounts.db")

            cursor = conn.cursor()

            Name = self.ent_Name.get()
            MemberID = self.ent_MemberID.get()

            List = [Name, MemberID]

            cursor.execute("DELETE FROM members(Name, MemberID) VALUES (?,?)",(Name, MemberID))
            conn.commit()
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what happens when you run your code? Does it delete the wrong record? Does it crash? Does it delete the correct record from the wrong database?

Comment: it comes up with a: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax for delete.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM members WHERE Name=? AND MemberID=?",(Name, MemberID))
```

Comment: Hello, I inserted this line into my code and the same error is still appearing.

Comment: I had a superflous ``)`` at the end, edited the answer.

Comment: Hello, I changed it and the error is gone, thanks for your help.